# Android Audio Track Play with noise

Tags: java, android, audio, udp

I am working on a peer to peer to voice call application in Android for my college project. I found sample code for streaming the mic audio through UDP. That code will help me to stream the WAV file through UDP. But it doesn't play some files properly. And also that code doesn't stream mic audio.
Please help me.

```
public class UdpStream extends Activity {


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.udpstream);
        Button btnSend = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSend);
        btnSend.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "btnSend clicked");
                SendAudio();
            }
        });

        Button btnRecv = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnRecv);
        btnRecv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "btnRecv clicked");
                RecvAudio();
            }
        });

        Button btnStrmic = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnStrmic);
        btnStrmic.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "btnStrmic clicked");
                SendMicAudio();
            }
        });

    }

    static final String LOG_TAG = "UdpStream";
    static final String AUDIO_FILE_PATH = "/sdcard/1.wav";
    static final int AUDIO_PORT = 2048;
    static final int SAMPLE_RATE = 8000;
    static final int SAMPLE_INTERVAL = 20; // milliseconds
    static final int SAMPLE_SIZE = 2; // bytes per sample
    static final int BUF_SIZE = SAMPLE_INTERVAL*SAMPLE_INTERVAL*SAMPLE_SIZE*2;
    protected String host="localhost";
    public void RecvAudio()
    {
        Thread thrd = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() 
            {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "start recv thread, thread id: "
                    + Thread.currentThread().getId());
                AudioTrack track = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 
                        SAMPLE_RATE, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO, 
                        AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, BUF_SIZE, 
                        AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
                track.play();
                try
                {
                    DatagramSocket sock = new DatagramSocket(AUDIO_PORT);
                    byte[] buf = new byte[BUF_SIZE];

                    while(true)
                    {
                        DatagramPacket pack = new DatagramPacket(buf, BUF_SIZE);
                        sock.receive(pack);
                        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "recv pack: " + pack.getLength());
                        track.write(pack.getData(), 0, pack.getLength());
                    }
                }
                catch (SocketException se)
                {
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "SocketException: " + se.toString());
                }
                catch (IOException ie)
                {
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "IOException" + ie.toString());
                }
            } // end run
        });
        thrd.start();
    }
    Toast toast;
    int port=3008;
    public void SendAudio()
    {

        toast=Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), port + " : " + host , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

        Thread thrd = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() 
            {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "start send thread, thread id: "
                    + Thread.currentThread().getId());
                long file_size = 0;
                int bytes_read = 0;
                int bytes_count = 0;
                File audio = new File(AUDIO_FILE_PATH);
                FileInputStream audio_stream = null;
                file_size = audio.length();
                byte[] buf = new byte[BUF_SIZE];
                try
                {

                    EditText d= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txttohost);
                    host=d.getText().toString();


                    if(host=="")
                    {
                    port=2048;
                    host="localhost";

                    }
                    port=2048;
                    InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName(host);
                    toast.setText(port + " : " + addr.toString());
                    toast.show();
                    DatagramSocket sock = new DatagramSocket();
                    audio_stream = new FileInputStream(audio);

                    while(bytes_count < file_size)
                    {
                        bytes_read = audio_stream.read(buf, 0, BUF_SIZE);
                        DatagramPacket pack = new DatagramPacket(buf, bytes_read,
                                addr, port);
                        sock.send(pack);
                        bytes_count += bytes_read;
                        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "bytes_count : " + bytes_count);
                        Thread.sleep(SAMPLE_INTERVAL, 0);
                    }
                }
                catch (InterruptedException ie)
                {
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "InterruptedException");
                }
                catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe)
                {
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "FileNotFoundException");
                }
                catch (SocketException se)
                {
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "SocketException");
                }
                catch (UnknownHostException uhe)
                {
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "UnknownHostException");
                }
                catch (IOException ie)
                {
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "IOException");
                }
            } // end run
        });
        thrd.start();
    }

    public void SendMicAudio()
    {
        Thread thrd = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() 
            {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "start SendMicAudio thread, thread id: "
                    + Thread.currentThread().getId());
                AudioRecord audio_recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT, SAMPLE_RATE,
                            AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
                            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
                            AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(SAMPLE_RATE,
                                    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
                                    AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT) * 10);
                int bytes_read = 0;
                int bytes_count = 0;
                byte[] buf = new byte[BUF_SIZE];
                try
                {
                    InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
                    DatagramSocket sock = new DatagramSocket();

                    while(true)
                    {
                        bytes_read = audio_recorder.read(buf, 0, BUF_SIZE);
                        DatagramPacket pack = new DatagramPacket(buf, bytes_read,
                                addr, AUDIO_PORT);
                        sock.send(pack);
                        bytes_count += bytes_read;
                        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "bytes_count : " + bytes_count);
                        Thread.sleep(SAMPLE_INTERVAL, 0);
                    }
                }
                catch (InterruptedException ie)
                {
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "InterruptedException");
                }
//                catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe)
//                {
//                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "FileNotFoundException");
//                }
                catch (SocketException se)
                {
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "SocketException");
                }
                catch (UnknownHostException uhe)
                {
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "UnknownHostException");
                }
                catch (IOException ie)
                {
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "IOException");
                }
            } // end run
        });
        thrd.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for as concern with my question....

The Solution is Always while playing the Audio through out speaker will cause Some noise....

So i found the following two solution to fix that...

1) Play the audio through ear piece

> audio_service.setSpeakerphoneOn(false);
>         audio_service.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
>         audio_service.setRouting(AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL,AudioManager.ROUTE_EARPIECE,
>   AudioManager.ROUTE_ALL);

2) Next way to do use Some Audio Codec for encoding and Decoding Your Audio to play that in noiseless..